# Azure DevOps SQL Dacpac release job - extracting build variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a CI/CD pipeline running that releases a database (Visual Studio 2017 + SSDT) in Azure DevOps pipelines. The process works fine, however I am trying to log some Build information into the database.

I created a logging table for logging build information and used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) as a reference for the information I want logged. I have setup the variables in the Project Properties "SQLCMD Variables" section to match the ones I want (BuildID, Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionName, Build.Reason, Build.SourceBranch, Build.SourceVersion, Build.SourceMessage).

[image: Visual Studio Project SQLCMD Variables]

I put into the "Additional SQLPackage.ext Arguments" for the Azure DevOps release the sqlcmd for extracting these parameters:

```
/v:BuildID=$(Build.BuildId) /v:BuildTriggeredBy=$(Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionName) /v:BuildReason=$(Build.Reason) /v:BuildSourceBranch=$(Build.SourceBranch) /v:BuildSourceVersion=$(Build.SourceVersion) /v:BuildSourceMessage=$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)
```

I created a post deployment script which will log these values into a logging table. Theoretically every time a release is successful, the build information should be logged:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ReleaseLog ([BuildID],[TriggeredBy],[Reason],[SourceBranch],[SourceVersion],[SourceVersionMessage]) 
VALUES ('$(BuildID)','$(BuildTriggeredBy)','$(BuildReason)','$(BuildSourceBranch)','$(BuildSourceVersion)','$(BuildSourceMessage)')
```

Some of these work fine, but others don't work at all. The ones that work are:
**BuildID, SourceBranch, SourceVersion**

The ones that don't (and return "$(VariableName)") are:
**Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionName, Build.Reason, Build.SourceVersion**

[image: Results in logging table]

Anyone know why? I have checked all the variables and they appear to be OK. I believe all the variables I am including should be available at the end of the release. It seems strange that some of the variables would work when others do not. I have triple checked (copied and pasted variable names between VS and release pipeline, plus copied the exact names from the MS site), so it doesn't seem like a code problem.  Azure DevOps bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure DevOps SQL Dacpac release job - extracting build variables

That because you created a post deployment script in the **release pipeline**, which could not get all those predefined variables in the **build** pipeline.

You could check those variables in the [Classic release and artifacts variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---primary-artifact). The variables **Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionName**, **Build.Reason**, **Build.SourceVersionMessage** are not in the Classic release and artifacts variables, it in the [Use predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). That the reason why you could not get those specify variables in your release pipeline.

(*You said `Build.SourceVersion` in your question, but according to the image you provided, it seems you wrote the wrong variable, it should be `Build.SourceVersionMessage`*).

To resolve this issue, you could try to create post deployment script in the **build** pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that finds this, hopefully this will fill in a few more blanks.

## Define a variable in the database project

First you have to define a variable in the database project file's properties (here I called mine YatesEnv):
[image: Database project SQLCMD variables tab]

1. Right click on the project and view its properties
2. Select SQLCMD Variables
3. Add a new variable with a default

## Update a script file

Next update your Post or Pre deployment script file to use it and note how it comes through as a string, but I put it in a variable to help me when testing the script:

```sql
declare @Environment varchar(200) = '$(YatesEnv)'

if @Environment = 'DEV' 
begin
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Person] ([FirstName],[LastName],[DateOfBirth]) VALUES ('Bob', 'DEV', DATEADD(YEAR, -30, GETDATE()))
end
else if @Environment = 'QA' 
begin
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Person] ([FirstName],[LastName],[DateOfBirth]) VALUES ('Bob', 'QA', DATEADD(YEAR, -30, GETDATE()))
end
```

## Update the release pipeline task

We want all this to be built once and then in each part of your RELEASE pipeline, you would populate the variable like this:
[image: Release pipeline SQL Server Database deploy task]

1. Select the "SQL Server Database deploy" task
2. Update the "Additional Arguments" section using the /v:VariableName="some value" syntax.  Note that I used double quotes for the variable contents because single quotes will result in a pipeline error.